# How to monitor external traffic to my local IIS server?

Tags: mobile, iis-7.5, fiddler

I'm developing for mobile devices and to debug I connect devices on WIFI to my IP address. It works well for developing on hardware and debugging on my machine. The only thing I can't make to work is how do I set up Fiddler so it sees traffic coming from external clients?

If I open my site from browser on same machine - fiddler get's it. But when I connect to my PC by IP address from another machine - fiddler doesn't see it.

I have proper settings (I think)

[image]

Comment: you should install fiddler on that another machine

Comment: Another machine is Android phone :) I want to see traffic coming to IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure Fiddler as a reverse proxy. See [Using Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy).

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by simply changing the IIS Application Pool whose traffic I wanted to inspect to run under my identity, since Fiddler seems to only capture traffic of the logged in user by default.  Just make sure your user has all of the necessary permissions required by IIS; I'm an admin so this wasn't an issue for me. And of course, don't forget to change the IIS Application Pool identity back when you are done.

The other option of course is to instead log in as the user that the IIS Application Pool is running as (if it's not a service account like `Network Service`) and then run Fiddler while logged in as that other user.